# How to constraint an image panning to the edges of the Box in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

How to constraint an image panning to the edges of the Box in Compose?

I'm using `pointerInput(Unit) { detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation -> }}` to control zooming and panning.

I'm solving this panning problem when the image is minimized to `1f` with `if (scale.value == 1f) 0f else panOffsetX`. I want to do the same for the image zoomed-in (1f < scale <= 3f)

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RectangleShape)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Gray)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                val constraintZoom = when {
                    scale.value > 3f -> 3f
                    scale.value < 1f -> 1f
                    else -> (scale.value * zoom)
                }
                scale.value = constraintZoom
                panOffset += pan
                panOffsetX += pan.x
                panOffsetY += pan.y
                centroidOffset = centroid
                rotationState.value += rotation
            }
        }
) {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = maxOf(1f, minOf(3f, scale.value)),
                scaleY = maxOf(1f, minOf(3f, scale.value)),
                translationX = if (scale.value == 1f) 0f else panOffsetX,
                translationY = if (scale.value == 1f) 0f else panOffsetY,
            ),
        contentDescription = null,
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.my_sample_image)
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Trick is to limit it using your Composable size and zoom level

```
val maxX = (size.width * (zoom - 1) / 2f)
val maxY = (size.height * (zoom - 1) / 2f)

offset = newOffset
offset = Offset(
    newOffset.x.coerceIn(-maxX, maxX),
    newOffset.y.coerceIn(-maxY, maxY)
```

Full Implementation

States

```
var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
```

Modifier

```
  val imageModifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .aspectRatio(4 / 3f)
        .clipToBounds()
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTransformGestures(
                onGesture = { _, gesturePan, gestureZoom, _ ->
                    
                    zoom = (zoom * gestureZoom).coerceIn(1f, 3f)
                    val newOffset = offset + gesturePan.times(zoom)
                    
                    val maxX = (size.width * (zoom - 1) / 2f)
                    val maxY = (size.height * (zoom - 1) / 2f)

                    offset = Offset(
                        newOffset.x.coerceIn(-maxX, maxX),
                        newOffset.y.coerceIn(-maxY, maxY)
                    )
                }
            )
        }
        .onSizeChanged {
            size = it
        }
        .graphicsLayer {
            translationX = offset.x
            translationY = offset.y
            scaleX = zoom
            scaleY = zoom
        }
```

Comment: Finally a solution that works for me. I had problems while scrolling. Guess the problem was the offset.