# Zooming each image inside LazyColumn causes content to overlap

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, pdfrenderer, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I am trying to zoom images which are items inside my LazyColumn but when i try to zoom in it overlaps content with the other images and the scrolling of lazycolumn also becomes too difficult

```
 var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
 var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f)) }

LazyColumn() {
                            items(mPdfRenderer?.pageCount!!) { message ->
Box(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxSize()
                                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                                            detectTransformGestures { _, pan, zoom, _ ->
                                                scale *= zoom
                                                offset = Offset(
                                                    (offset.x + pan.x).coerceIn(
                                                        -200.dp.toPx(),
                                                        200.dp.toPx()
                                                    ),
                                                    (offset.y + pan.y).coerceIn(
                                                        -200.dp.toPx(),
                                                        200.dp.toPx()
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            }
                                        }
                                ) {
                                    Image(
                                        bitmap = bitmap!!.asImageBitmap(),
                                        contentDescription = "some useful description",
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Gray)
                                            .scale(scale)
                                            .offset(offset.x.dp, offset.y.dp)
                                            .aspectRatio(1f)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I am actually creating a pdf viewer. How can the zooming be improved so that content is not overlapped and the vertical scrolling remains smooth?

Check [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eEtai7_tV2cj43na1tZ2VkinA9aGIVmv/view?usp=sharing) to understand the zooming issue

Comment: If you wish to contain draw area inside its Image or container call Modifier.clipToBounds(). But there are several things that could be improved in your code. Such as consuming selectively. Zooming from center of fingers/pointer instead of Image center and limit panning to not leave blank space on each side.

Comment: You can check out this for which specific setup you wish to have not even using the library it's easy to implement a gesture specific to your needs. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Zoom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your code is you are keeping single

```
 var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
 var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f)) }
```

which applies to every item in LazyColumn while each pages should have its own scale and offset properties.

```
private class PdfProperties() {
    var zoom = mutableStateOf(1f)
    var offset = mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
}
```

or

```
val offsetMap = remember {
    mutableStateMapOf<Int, Offset>()
}

val scaleMap = remember {
    mutableStateMapOf<Int, Float>()
}
```

then you should apply and change offset and scale for each page.

This is how you should implement it with the Modifier which clips PDF page as in this ZoomableList.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72668732/5457853

For smooth scrolling you should **consume** `PointerInputChange` conditionally when number of fingers is bigger than 1 or zoom is bigger than 1f as in answer below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76021552/5457853

This custom gesture i wrote that is available in link above or as library [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Extended-Gestures/) makes it easy to consume PointerInputChange conditionally as

```
            Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {

                //zoom in/out and move around
                detectTransformGestures(
                    pass = PointerEventPass.Initial,
                    onGesture = { gestureCentroid: Offset,
                                  gesturePan: Offset,
                                  gestureZoom: Float,
                                  _,
                                  _,
                                  changes: List<PointerInputChange> ->



// Consume touch when multiple fingers down
// or zoom > 1f
// This prevents LazyColumn scrolling
                        val size = changes.size
                        if (size > 1) {
                            changes.forEach { it.consume() }
                        }
                    }
                )
            })
```

Also you can refer this answer too.

[How to handle horizontal scroll gesture combined with transform gestures in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370595/how-to-handle-horizontal-scroll-gesture-combined-with-transform-gestures-in-jetp/76374985#76374985)

### Extra

As i asked in comments if you want to limit zoom into `Image` you should also call Modifier.clipToBounds if you wish to limit zoom inside Box also you might want to change zoom center and empty area by limiting pan in limits with

```
detectTransformGestures(
    onGesture = { _, gesturePan, gestureZoom, _ ->

        zoom = (zoom * gestureZoom).coerceIn(1f, 3f)
        val newOffset = offset + gesturePan.times(zoom)

        val maxX = (size.width * (zoom - 1) / 2f)
        val maxY = (size.height * (zoom - 1) / 2f)

        offset = Offset(
            newOffset.x.coerceIn(-maxX, maxX),
            newOffset.y.coerceIn(-maxY, maxY)
        )
    }
)
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72856350/5457853

And for natural pan and zooming which happens center of fingers instead of center of screen you can refer this official code

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputScope).detectTransformGestures(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function4)

You can also consider checking this zoom library which offers features i mentioned above and more out of the box.

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Zoom

Comment: Hello @Thracian Would you mind looking at this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816495/how-to-move-zoom-image-in-lazycolumn
 I can zoom image but can not move after zoom in LazyColumn. I have implemented this solution based on your answer. 
Thank you

Comment: Instead of `detectTransformGestures` see `detectCustomTransformGestures` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370595/how-to-handle-horizontal-scroll-gesture-combined-with-transform-gestures-in-jetp.

Answer (score 2):

You can try first one of the approaches suggested in "[Zoom Lazycolumn item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72667120/6309)"

It involves:

- **Creating a Custom Gesture Detector**: Instead of using the default [`detectTransformGestures`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputScope).detectTransformGestures(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function4)), a custom gesture detector `detectZoom` is introduced to only detect zoom gestures, thus allowing the `LazyColumn` to still scroll properly.
- **Using Modifier.zIndex**: To prevent overlapping issues, [`Modifier.zIndex`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).zIndex(kotlin.Float)) is used. When the user zooms an image, the `zIndex` ensures the zoomed image is drawn on top of other images.

So first, define the custom zoom gesture:

```kotlin
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectZoom(
    onGesture: (zoom: Float) -> Unit,
) {
    // [Same as provided in the SO answer]
}
```

Next, in your LazyColumn:

```kotlin
val list = /* Your data source. In the given example, it's a list of image URLs. */

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    itemsIndexed(list) { index, item ->
        var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }

        Image(
            // Adjust based on your image source. In the example, they're using an online image.
            bitmap = bitmap!!.asImageBitmap(), 
            contentDescription = "some useful description",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectZoom { zoom ->
                        scale *= zoom
                    }
                }
                .graphicsLayer {
                    scaleX = maxOf(1f, minOf(3f, scale))
                    scaleY = maxOf(1f, minOf(3f, scale))
                }
                .zIndex(scale)
        )
    }
}
```

That would:

- make sure only zoom gestures are detected, not panning.
- leverage `zIndex` to make sure zoomed images appear above other images to prevent overlapping.
- simplify the zoom logic by focusing only on the zoom aspect and not mixing it with panning.

Comment: Does not work, check this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eEtai7_tV2cj43na1tZ2VkinA9aGIVmv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Chupbae I cannot (site is blocked). Any chance for a Github gist or small repository?

Comment: https://github.com/kyadalu1/PdfLazy

Comment: What i mean  is the image in the right in the link with two images with red borders. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922205/how-to-have-natural-pan-and-zoom-with-modifier-graphicslayer-pointerinput  If you assign pointerInput before graphicsLayer that touch area is stationary while you might change where image drawn. So in that case you should only start the motion again from original bounds of Image or Box not where you translated graphics layer

Comment: Using Modifier.zIndex: To prevent overlapping issues, Modifier.zIndex is used. When the user zooms an image, the zIndex ensures the zoomed image is drawn on top of other images.This is not a good thing especially with PDF files because when you zoom in but you do not increase the bounds of Modifier.pointerInput. After you lift you finger the area out of original Image bounds might not react to user interaction if user touches out of original bounds

Comment: @Thracian OK, The issue seems to be that the touch detection area (from pointerInput) doesn't change, even though the visual representation of the image (from graphicsLayer) does. This discrepancy can cause touch gestures to be detected incorrectly, especially when the image is panned or zoomed outside its original bounds.

Comment: What's incorrect in OPs code is he's keeping one offset and zoom State that he applies to every page. Even if he zooms page one every page is zoomed and overlap with each other. And even after correcting that he might need to limit zoom area with Modifier.clipToBounds if not, he might consider changing order of pointerInput and graphicsLayer if he wants to apply gesture in zoomed image bounds but not original bounds which would not have any effect if user tries to pan out of original image bounds

Comment: And if he decides to limit zoom and transformation bounds it would also be good idea to limit pan to not have empty space near edges or sides and another improvement over this also would be to add natural zoom using the code from official pages that adjusts centroid with changing TranformationOrigin

Comment: Natural zoom code is available here. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputScope).detectTransformGestures(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function4)

Comment: @Thracian You are right; each page should indeed have its own scale and offset properties. The method you have proposed to maintain individual states for each page using a `mutableStateMapOf` or a dedicated `PdfProperties` class is a more accurate solution. It ensures that each page can be zoomed and panned independently. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks also as you pointed he needs to consume PointerInputChange when zoom is bigger than 1f or when user zooms with 2 fingers, etc. That's also another thing for smooth scrolling and zooming experience.

Comment: doing a proper PDF Viewer or zoomable images requires several steps but you can have any of them while each one improves user experience further